# How to get Raw mouse signal (x, y or displacement values) using python?

Tags: python, mouseevent, mouse, robotics

If i use libraries like pynput, I'm getting values which are mapped to screen, this value maxes out based on screen resolution.

I do not want that, I'm using my mouse for a robotic project, I want the raw values from my mouse to calculate displacement.

Kindly let me know if you have any answers. thanks.

I tried pynput etc. It does not help.

Comment: Have you tried setting a reference point and then calculating the distance from your mouse to that point?

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, I tried that, This is the program in my repo.

https://github.com/SujithChristopher/armbo/blob/master/mouse_delta/test.py

It seems to be inactive for a particular direction. 

Because, for example, if my reference is (0, 0), if I move my mouse to (10, 10), then my mouse delta is (10, 10).

but I cannot move to (-10, -10) because that is not allowed, since it is mapped to the screen. 

I think "Mouse Delta" is the right term, if you have any ideas, do suggest. Thanks.